# Find a string from Cell, and delete 4-5 rows attached to it and then move to next cell

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm looking for is, I need to find out if a cell contains ".L" in it, if yes, the entire row along with 4 more rows needs to be deleted and this series goes on until last set of data.

For example:
There would be hundreds of dataset like shown below, out of which "RIC" contains ".L".

TID: xxx, Symbol=xxx, Date=xxx, **RIC=EPWN.L** , CUSIP=xxx, SEDOL=xxx
DataStream: xxxx
Bloomberg.: xxxx
Market....: xxxx

TID: xxx, Symbol=xxx, Date=xxx, **RIC=BAR.BR** , CUSIP=xxx, SEDOL=xxx
DataStream: xxx
Bloomberg.: xxx
Market....: xxx

Need to delete the entire set if any RIC is having ".L". So in the end, what should I get is dataset without ".L"

Please help

Below is the vba but it is not working:

```
Range("b2:b2000").ClearContents
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim serchstring As String
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 
searchstring = ".l"
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In rng
If UCase(cell.Value) Like "*" & UCase(searchstring) Then
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(2, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(3, 1).Value = "NA"

cell.Font.Bold = True
cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 
End If
Next cell
 
 
Cells.Select
 
With ActiveSheet
 
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:B").AutoFilter
.Range("A:B").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="NA"
 
Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.AutoFilterMode = False
 
End With
 
With ActiveSheet
 
.AutoFilterMode = False
 
.Range("A:B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=""

Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see what error it throws and on which line.

Comment: It is giving 404 error message

Answer (score 0):

If your program is not erasing the row, I think the issue lies with these lines:

```vb
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(2, 1).Value = "NA"
cell.Offset(3, 1).Value = "NA"
```

Offset is returning a single cell so you are only erasing a single cell. But your post says you want to erase the whole row. To reference the row, I suggest:

```vb
cell.Offset(0, 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
cell.Offset(1, 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
cell.Offset(2, 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
cell.Offset(3, 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
```

Which can be reduced to a single line like:

```vb
cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow.ClearContents
```

Or if you don't want to leave blank rows behind you can directly delete the rows like:

```vb
cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow.Delete
```

But if you do repetitive deleting, you'll notice that Excel stutters and the execution is slow. So I suggest saving the rows to be deleted into a range variable and then deleting them all at once at the end. Use Union() to add ranges together.

```vb
If rToBeDeleted Is Nothing Then
    Set rToBeDeleted = cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow
Else
    Set rToBeDeleted = Union(rToBeDeleted, cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow)
End If
'And then at the end
rToBeDeleted.Delete
```

And if you do it this way, you don't need to do any of that autofilter deleting.

Edit:
For clarity, here is how I suggest your code be structured after applying my suggestions:

```vb
Range("b2:b2000").ClearContents
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rToBeDeleted As Range
Dim serchstring As String
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 
searchstring = "*.L"
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In rng
    If UCase(cell.Value) Like searchstring Then
        If rToBeDeleted Is Nothing Then
            Set rToBeDeleted = cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow
        Else
            Set rToBeDeleted = Union(rToBeDeleted, cell.Offset(0).Resize(4).EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next cell


rToBeDeleted.Delete
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it is still not working. It is just removing the gaps between 2 dataset. Instead i want to delete whole dataset containing (.L) in RIC.

Comment: @Crox I have added an example of how to implement my suggestions that should work. Please take a look and let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: This not working......this is deleting the whole data instead of deleting only ".L" dataset. please help :(

Comment: The code you posted suggested that you wanted to delete not just the row containing ".L" but the row above and two rows below. If that is not correct then you need to adjust `cell.Offset(0).Resize(4)` to something else. Perhaps removing `.Offset(0).Resize(4)`.

Comment: That or maybe after finding a match, skip the next few rows to not re-match in the same set.

Comment: Yes that's correct, i want to delete the row containing (.L) and 1 row above and 4 below rows. Would that be possible ? Or we can just do this.....just delete the row containing (.L) and 4 rows below??? Anything possible ?

Comment: Any progress here ?

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: @Crox try posting a new question to Stack Overflow with more clarity about what your data looks like and what you want your code to do.  I will not be updating my answer here, as there are not enough details for me to improve my answer.